# Trouble building BGFX on Windows w/ MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, bgfx

Trying to build bgfx. Following the documentation for building it, I run `make mingw-gcc`.
This, originally resulted in `Set MINGW environment variable` & `make.exe": *** [mingw-gcc-debug32] Error 127` so I set the MINGW environment variable, and this got rid of the `Set MINGW environment variable` message. However, I still get the same error:
`make.exe": *** [mingw-gcc-debug32] Error 127`, and I also noticed:
`C:/(directory to my project)/extern/bgfx/C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe: No such file or directory`. Like the directory to `make.exe` was being appended onto the end of the directory to bgfx. I'm at a complete loss as to why or even how this is happening, and I've no idea how to fix it. I've tried changing the `MINGW` environment variable, using `mingw32-make`, specifying `mingw-gcc-release64`, etc... To be honest, I don't even know if this is related solely to bgfx or if it's a problem with make or whatever Idk... Shooting my shot here to see if anyone can help.
Thanks.

Comment: I doubt we can help fix this problem given only the information in the question. Also it seems you are using an old version of msys

Comment: @drescherjm I apologize if the question was vague, but you've still helped! I still don't know what was actually wrong with it originally, but after installing msys and mingw properly, it worked perfectly. So, thanks :)

Comment: Sometimes I get lucky with a guess.